# Codeigniter .Init function is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification

I am working in codeigniter project.Because of some of its requirements(send push notification to mobile devices) i had to use an external library which is probably written in native PHP .When i run the whole code after configuring it it gives me 
"**Init function is not allowed**. " That response is coming from the **constructor** of the **Pushnotification.php** File.
 My Code

**PushNotification.php**

```
<?php 
// Server file

class PushNotifications {


// (Android)API access key from Google API's Console.
private static $API_ACCESS_KEY = '';


// (iOS) Private key's passphrase.
private static $passphrase = '';


// (Windows Phone 8) The name of our push channel.
    private static $channelName = "";

// Change the above three vriables as per your app.

public function __construct() {
    exit('Init function is not allowed');
}

    // Sends Push notification for Android users
public function android($data, $reg_id) {
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $message = array(
            'title' => $data['mtitle'],
            'message' => $data['mdesc'],
            'subtitle' => '',
            'tickerText' => '',
            'msgcnt' => 1,
            'vibrate' => 1
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' .self::$API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => array($reg_id),
            'data' => $message,
        );

        return $this->useCurl($url, $headers, json_encode($fields));
    }

// Sends Push's toast notification for Windows Phone 8 users
public function WP($data, $uri) {
    $delay = 2;
    $msg =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
                "<wp:Toast>" .
                    "<wp:Text1>".htmlspecialchars($data['mtitle'])."</wp:Text1>" .
                    "<wp:Text2>".htmlspecialchars($data['mdesc'])."</wp:Text2>" .
                "</wp:Toast>" .
            "</wp:Notification>";

    $sendedheaders =  array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml',
        'Accept: application/*',
        'X-WindowsPhone-Target: toast',
        "X-NotificationClass: $delay"
    );

    $response = $this->useCurl($uri, $sendedheaders, $msg);

    $result = array();
    foreach(explode("\n", $response) as $line) {
        $tab = explode(":", $line, 2);
        if (count($tab) == 2)
            $result[$tab[0]] = trim($tab[1]);
    }

    return $result;
}

    // Sends Push notification for iOS users
public function iOS($data, $devicetoken) {

    $deviceToken = $devicetoken;

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    // ck.pem is your certificate file
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', self::$passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => array(
            'title' => $data['mtitle'],
            'body' => $data['mdesc'],
         ),
        'sound' => 'default'
    );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);

    if (!$result)
        return 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        return 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

}

// Curl 
private function useCurl(&$model, $url, $headers, $fields = null) {
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($url) {
            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            if ($fields) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            }

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);

            return $result;
    }
    }

}
?>
```

**TestNotification.php**

```
public function Testnotification()
{

    $this->load->library('PushNotifications');

    // Message payload

    $msg_payload = array (
        'mtitle' => 'Test push notification title',
        'mdesc' => 'Test push notification body',
    );

    // For Android
    $regId = 'APA91bHdOmMHiRo5jJRM1jvxmGqhComcpVFDqBcPfLVvaieHeFI9WVrwoDeVVD1nPZ82rV2DxcyVv-oMMl5CJPhVXnLrzKiacR99eQ_irrYogy7typHQDb5sg4NB8zn6rFpiBuikNuwDQzr-2abV6Gl_VWDZlJOf4w';


    // For iOS
    $deviceToken = 'FE66489F304DC75B8D6E8200DFF8A456E8DAEACEC428B427E9518741C92C6660';


    // For WP8
    $uri = 'http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/sin/HmQAAAD1XJMXfQ8SR0b580NcxIoD6G7hIYP9oHvjjpMC2etA7U_xy_xtSAh8tWx7Dul2AZlHqoYzsSQ8jQRQ-pQLAtKW/d2luZG93c3Bob25lZGVmYXVsdA/EKTs2gmt5BG_GB8lKdN_Rg/WuhpYBv02fAmB7tjUfF7DG9aUL4';

    // Replace the above variable values


        PushNotifications::android($msg_payload, $regId);

        PushNotifications::WP8($msg_payload, $uri);

        PushNotifications::iOS($msg_payload, $deviceToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove or comment the `exit` line at the `PushNotification` contructor:

**PushNotification.php**

```
<?php 

class PushNotifications {

    public function __construct() {
        //exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }
...
```